# Find the Sequence of a Generating Function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am given generating function $f(x)=x^m(1-x)^m$ where $m\in\mathbb{N^*}$ and I would like to find it's sequence.

So my steps on that problem so far are  $f(x)=x^m(1-x)^m=x^m\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n{m \choose n}x^n=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n{m \choose n}x^{n+m}$

and then I find it hard to leave alone $x^n$ so I can get $f(n)$.Is there any method that I can use for that?

Comment: What is $i$? Should that be $n$?

Comment: You mean the sum goes from $n=0$ to $n=m$.

Comment: Yhea sorry I update it.

Comment: Is $m$ a nonnegative integer?

Comment: Yhea and cannot be zero too.

Comment: You say you want to "get $f(n)$" but $f(n)=n^m(1-n)^m.$ I think you want the coefficients of the Taylor series for $f(x)$ about $x=0$?

Comment: I want to find $f(n)$ when $n\in\mathbb{N}$ no when $x\in\mathbb{R}$. I mean I have a generating function and I want to find it's sequence. If for example I have $f^*(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n)x^n$, $f(n)$ is what I want.

Comment: That is our definition we are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(k)$ is the coefficient of $x^k$, so using your formula, we get
\begin{equation*}
  f(k) = \begin{cases} 0 & k<m \\ (-1)^{k-m}\binom{m}{k-m} & k \ge m \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Comment: So If we expand my formula we will get $\sum_{k=m}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-m}{m \choose k-m}x^n$ and from here we can conclude that?If that is true, should't need to start our sum from 0 and not from $m$?